# Why am I getting ValueError when using min() to find the closest matching RGB value?

Tags: python, list, numpy, min

My code should

- take an image
- determine the number of unique colours
- match each of those colours to the nearest RGB of a pre-defined list of colours

The matching is failing on the 90th (of 113) unique colour with
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I have an np array of several hundred useable colours in the format

```
COLOURS = np.array([
[252,252,252],
[255,226,226],
[255,201,201],
[245,173,173],
[241,135,135],
[227,109,109],
[191,45,45],
[254,215,204],
....
[70,5,45]
])
```

My matching code is

```
def findClosestRGB(rgb):
    global COLOURS
    print("RGB: ", str(rgb))
    r, g, b = rgb
    color_diffs = []
    for color in COLOURS:
        cr, cg, cb = color
        #print("cr, cg, cb: "+ str(cr),","+str(cg),","+str(cb))
        color_diff = sqrt((r - cr)**2 + (g - cg)**2 + (b - cb)**2)
        color_diffs.append((color_diff, color))
    print(min(color_diffs))
    return min(color_diffs)[1]
```

The trace is:

```
RGB:  [176 175 175]
(3.0, array([174, 174, 177]))
uniqueColour:  [176 175 175]  matchedRGB:  [174 174 177]
RGB:  [184 188 178]
(9.848857801796104, array([184, 184, 187]))
uniqueColour:  [184 188 178]  matchedRGB:  [184 184 187]
RGB:  [191 191 191]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CreatePaletteFileV0.1.py", line 1461, in <module>
    matchedRGB = findClosestRGB(uniqueColour)
  File "CreatePaletteFileV0.1.py", line 1429, in findClosestRGB
    print(min(color_diffs))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I cannot seem to pinpoint the cause of the error - maybe I am using min() inappropriately.

In case it is useful I want the code to replace the colours in the original image with those from my distinct colour set.

Answer (score 0):

You *are* using the builtin `min()` inappropriately. The builtin `min()` compares each element of the iterable against other elements. Since each element of a numpy array is the entire *row*, it ends up checking if one row is less than another row. For example:

```
row1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
row2 = np.array([-4, 5, -6])

if row1 < row2:
    print("less")
```

which results in the same error you see. This is because comparing one numpy array to another gives you a numpy array where each element is the result of the element-wise comparison of the two arrays.
i.e.

```
>>> print(row1 < row2)
[ False True False]
```

An array has an unambiguous boolean value, so cannot be used as an `if` condition without condensing it down to a single boolean using `any()` or `all()`. Of course, the builtin `min()` doesn't know that it's looking at numpy arrays, so it won't do this `any()` or `all()` step, and you get that error.

You could use `np.min()` to get what you want. However, hen you have a `numpy` array, you do yourself a disservice by ignoring the amazing powers of `numpy`, such as [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and SIMD operations.

```
def findClosestRGB(rgb):
    # This is not needed because you never assign to the variable in this function
    # global COLOURS

    # numpy can broadcast arrays so that when you subtract a (3,) array 
    # from a (N, 3) array, it automatically subtracts the (3,) array from 
    # each row of the (N, 3)
    color_diffs = COLOURS - rgb

    # You can specify the axis argument to many numpy functions to apply them
    # along a specific axis
    color_diffs_norm = np.linalg.norm(color_diffs, axis=1)

    # np.ndarray.argmin() gives the index of the smallest value
    min_color_diff_index = color_diffs_norm.argmin()

    # Finally, return that color
    return COLOURS[min_color_diff_index, :]
```

Comment: Thanks #Pranav. I will definitely have to learn more about numpy as this is my first try with the library. I did try your code but on the first unique  colour [0 0 0] but rather than selecting the closest colour ([0 0 0]) it chose [155  19  89] before erroring     
return COLOURS[min_color_diff_index, :]
IndexError: index 722 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 490

I will see if I can figure out why (I only programme occasionally)

Comment: @stuartfish apologies for that, I had a typo in my code. Change `min_color_diff_index = color_diffs.argmin()` to `min_color_diff_index = color_diffs_norm.argmin()`, and it should work. The (wrong) previous version found the index of the minimum value in the `Nx3` `color_diffs` array, which is not what we wanted -- we wanted to find the minimum of the L2-norms of `color_diffs`, which is what the fixed code does

Answer (score 0):

I found a piece of code which works (where subjects is my list of colours).

```
def nearest_colour( subjects, query ):
    return min( subjects, key = lambda subject: sum( (s - q) ** 2 for s, q in zip( subject, query ) ))
```

This code reduces the original 113 colours to 53 from my list.

Comment: Good find. However, note the performance difference between using the pure python function `min` with a lambda to calculate each row's difference separately (23 milliseconds on my computer) vs. using numpy's power as demonstrated in my answer (142 _micro_ seconds on my computer). That's a 161x speedup, which is _totally_ worth it since you're using numpy already.